# How to specific color of a group of segments ? R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have the sample data and plot it using ggplot2 geom_segment :

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(p=c(1,2), f=c("A","B"))
df2 <- data.frame(p=c(3,4), f=c("C","D"))
ggplot() + 
geom_segment(data=df1, mapping=aes(x=p-0.5, xend=p+0.5, y=1, yend=1, color=f)) + 
geom_segment(data=df2, mapping=aes(x=p-0.5, xend=p+0.5, y=1, yend=1, color=f))
```

the result figure will be : 
[image]

I can't understand why the two separate geom_segment() layers share the same legend? what is the logic behind this behavior?

How can I manually set the color of line "A" and line "B"?
I have tried to change them with the following command:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_segment(data=df1, mapping=aes(x=p-0.5, xend=p+0.5, y=1, yend=1, color=f)) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("A"="red", "B"="blue")) +  
geom_segment(data=df2, mapping=aes(x=p-0.5, xend=p+0.5, y=1, yend=1, color=f))
```

but the error message appears :

> Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 2
>   provided.

Thanks you very much

Comment: `color` is a single aesthetic and will produce only one legend, even if you use `color` as an aesthetic mapping in multiple geoms. `scale_color_manual` requires a number of colors equal to the number of unique values across all the variables that are mapped to the color aesthetic (four in this case). The default colors for four values are `hcl(seq(15,375,length=5)[1:4], 100, 65)`, or in general when there are n different levels of the variable(s) mapped to color `hcl(seq(15,375,length=n+1)[1:n], 100, 65)`..

Comment: Aha, Thank you eipi10. I can understand why they share the same legend now.

Comment: Does ggplot2 internally use this fucntion "hcl(seq(15,375,length=n+1)[1:n], 100, 65)" to extract color aesthetic? As far as i can see, If I just want to change one color of them, I should substitute it with other desired value.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how ggplot does it internally, but those are the default colors it uses for discrete values. But you can substitute any desired color for any level of the variable mapped to the color aesthetic.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the color of all segments by utilizing scale_color_manual:

```
ggplot() + geom_segment(data = df1,mapping = aes(x=p-0.5,xend = p + 0.5, y = 1,yend = 1, color=f)) +
    geom_segment(data = df2,mapping = aes(x=p-0.5,xend = p + 0.5, y = 1,yend = 1,color = f))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("B"="blue", "A"="green", "D"="red","C"="yellow"))
```